# Python:Numpy Function not yielding correct results

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, polynomial-math, polynomials

I had a question concerning the results of a polynomial equation while using python/numpy.
I have defined a function using a polynomial having a rather small leading coefficient.
The following is my code and the equation:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np 

def myfunction(X):
    return 9.06043895*10**(-9)*X**6-1.67073053*10**(-6)*X**5 + \
          7.49688511*10**(-5)*X**4 + 7.97984114*10**(-4)*X**3 - \
          6.07927087*10**(-2)*X**2 - 0.415861627*X + 80.62563

Input = np.arange(0, 100, 1)
Output = myfunction(Input)

plt.plot(Input, Output)
```

This yields the following plot:

[image]

The error seems to be in the way that the resultant Y is calculated as the array itself is off. (The values match the plot, but are in correct)

Sample of the exact same equation plotted using WolframAlpha:
(literal copy/paste from above minus the \'s and returns)

[image]

Can anyone help shed some light on this problem?

I have a feeling there may be some truncations possibly while handling the function, but I feel that this equation is not *that* bad...

Thank you all for your time and hopefully assistance.

Comment: Looks fine to me in python. Can you post the values you're getting for the `Output` array?

Comment: Just an aside, you can use the `np.polyval` function to evaluate a polynomial without having to type all the `X**6 + ... X**5` and so on.  So, an easier way to type your function might be: `coeffs = [9.06043895e-9, -1.67073053e-6, 7.49688511e-5, 7.97984114e-4, -6.07927087e-2, -0.415861627,  80.62563]` then 
`np.polyval(coeffs, X)`  Also notice that I used `9.06e-9` instead of `9.06*10**(9)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an `int` vs. `float` issue.  You're getting integer overflow:

```
>>> np.int32(100)**6
-727379968
>>> np.float32(100)**6
1000000000000.0
```

because `np.arange(0, 100, 1)` is giving you integers.

You can make them floats however you like-- I usually use `np.arange(0, 100, 1.0)`, but to be honest I prefer `np.linspace`.

With floats, I get:

[image: corrected curve]